# NHibernate table per hierarchy mapping issue

Tags: nhibernate

We have the following table structure:

```
tbl_A 
   A_ID INT PK 
   Type_ID INT 

tbl_EA 
   EA_ID INT PK 
   A_ID FK to tbl_A 
   C_ID INT (reference to other table based on Type_ID from tbl_A) 

tbl_C 
   C_ID INT PK
```

So, we're thinking tbl_A is abstract class, and each type is a 
subclass, discriminator based on Type_ID. But then we run into 
problems handling tbl_EA. It has a "fake" discriminator, in that you 
join to tbl_A in order to determine the type. This is b/c having a 
Type_ID column in tbl_EA is redundant, you have to join on tbl_A 
anyway to get that data (there are more columns to the tables, but not 
needed for this). Then, we have to somehow map the relationship b/w 
tbl_C and tbl_EA.

SQL to get all EA items for a C entity: select * from tbl_EA where 
C_ID =  AND A_ID IN (select A_ID from tbl_A where type_id = ).

Any ideas on how to set up mapping for these tables, and corresponding 
relationships? I feel like answer may lie in the formula of a 
discriminator, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the discriminator do a join.

Is A just a list of types, or an actual entity? Are A and EA one-to-one?

Generally, it's best to start with your desired object model and work from there, even if your table structure is fixed.

Comment: A is an entity. The relationship is: A is a template, and EA is a copy of the template for a given entity C, but EA only links to template and stores answers (A is a template of questions). So, A is one to many w/EA.

So the entity EA would have properties for the answers, and a property for A, and that's where our problem is - mapping that relationship. Adding a discriminator to tbl_EA I believe would solve our problems, and we do have some leeway in table changes, but would require change in other system, and have redundant data.